# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

Below is my code in IntelliJ

```
package com.example.helloWorld;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I got an error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:`enter code here`308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Kindly advice

Comment: package com.example.helloWorld;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}

Comment: How did you run this? What file is your code in -- is it directory/file: `com/example/helloWorld/HelloWorld.java`

Comment: The issue is re-solved, At first have not created package and class correctly, I rectified it and issue is resolved. Thanks for your time.